# How to update property in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to update property after some time .but it is not `reflecting` on view why ?

Here is my code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grjd1u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.ls = "dddd"
     setTimeout(function(){ 
      this.name ="helllllll"
     }, 3000);
  }
```

I am trying to update my `name`  property after `3` sec .but it is not updating.

Why change detection is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the interface `OnChanges` to get the name reference and do the change in the var `name` this function its executed after `ngInit` and `ngOnChanges` its triggered when you are using `@Input()` decorator [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ycwgar)

```
ngOnChanges(changes: any): void {
  this.ls = "dddd"
     setTimeout(() => { 
    this.name = "helllllll"
  }, 3000);

}
```

Comment: ok got it my question is when I  use this method `ApplicationRef.tick()` or `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` .because in Angular 1 whenever we use setTimout we need to run digest cycle , but here without this it work

Comment: Nice!, you don't need to manipulate `ChangeDetectorRef` everyting is going to be updated at time that you save you file. 

Check the demo that I did in the post

Comment: but here you did not use `ChangeDetectorRef``

Comment: because It is no necesary

Comment: so my Question is which case we run changdetectorref manually

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question, please  edit your post and describe your additional question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172122/discussion-between-abel-valdez-and-naveen).

Answer (score 1):

Because in your callback for `setTimeout`, `this` is the `Window` object, not your component instance. You can fix this by using an arrow function, which binds `this` to the context in which the function was declared:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.ls = "dddd"
   setTimeout(() => { 
      this.name = "helllllll"
   }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Also, you shouldn't really be modifying `@Input`s from a child component itself - the parent component is the one who modifies inputs - but this answers why your change detection "isn't working" at least.

Comment: will I change this `name` property on parent component ?

Comment: Totally agree with @matmo. Change the value of `name` in your parent component (i.e. `app.component.ts`) rather than changing an `@Input()` value! Change detection will then automatically kick in and do the rest!

Comment: ok got it my question is when will I  use this method `ApplicationRef.tick()` or `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` .because in Angular 1 whenever we use setTimout we need to run digest cycle , but here without this it work

Comment: In Angular you do not need to call any `detectChanges()` method whatsoever as the engine is doing this periodically in the background and is checking all the properties for changes. What you can do however is to disable the change detection mechanism or control it manually if you really need it.

Comment: @Bajro I don't want to disable the change detection mechanism .I  just want to understand or In which case we run manually change detection ?

Comment: @Bajro In angular 1 settimeout is out of  scope of `angular` then we need to update view using `apply` or digest method

Comment: @naveen Yes you are totally right. Angular 1 was not aware of certain changes like the ones done in a `setTimeout()` function, which is in fact asynchronous. But in Angular >= 2 the change detection is invoked automatically when a user provides some input or when a browser event is called. It also detects changes automatically when properties are updated after a new HTTP request. AND the mosit important fact for you is, that Angular >= 2 is also able to automatically detect changes that have been made in a `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` method.

Comment: @Bajro have you used any where these method  ApplicationRef.tick() or ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()  ? In your project ? will I use third party library to use this method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172123/discussion-between-naveen-and-bajro).

Answer (score 0):

Use Observable:

```
// Create observable
const myObservable = new Observable((observer) => {
    setInterval(() => observer.next({ name: 'John Doe', time: new Date().toString() }), 3000);
})

// Subscribe to the observable
myObservable.subscribe((x: any) => {
    this.name = `${x.name}, Time: ${x.time}`;
});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ce3x4v